# Sort albums by date in Banshee

Tags: banshee, sort, tag

Banshee has an option - sort albums by release date, not by name, but turning it on do nothing. All tags are filled correctly. Is at a bug or I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Banshee's option to "Sort an artist's albums by year, not title" currently affects the sort order in **only** the **full track list**. This option does not affect the order of albums in the album list (the grid with all the album covers). This has caused quite a bit of confusion -- see [Bug 544758](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=544758) and its 5 duplicates.

If, however, you mean that turning on that option doesn't change the sort order anywhere -- even in the full track list -- then that is definitely a bug, and you should [report it](http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/).

Answer (score 0):

This bug is also raised on lauchpad as [Bug 784301](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/784301)

Don't forget to mark the bug as affecting you.